# jssor thumbnails disappear

Tags: thumbnails, jssor

I've looked and looked for what should be a simple answer, and for some reason I can't find it.

I'm experimenting with this amazing slider gleaned from the example [here](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html).  I'd be happy if mine looked like this, considering that my slider has larger images.

When I reset the code to accommodate the larger images I lost the entire thumbnail panel and its black background.  Obviously I also lost the thumbnail navigation.

You can see from [my page](http://divr.ca/new/index-jssor.html) that I've added a border.  Regardless of the container size, the thumbnails have disappeared either way.

I would be grateful if someone points me to the code or js that deals with this.  I would also appreciate if someone gave me some idea about the many selectors such as .jssora05r and .jssora05rdn, none of which have any html equivalent and leave me wondering what purpose they serve or whether they can just be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use class name to define css for `slider1_container`.

```
.slider1_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 628px;
    /*border: 20px solid #E1D9CC;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    /*margin: 90px auto 0;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

And remove the following codes,

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 1152px ) {
    .slider1_container {
        max-width: 92%;
        border-width: 15px;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 800px ) {
    .slider1_container {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border-width: 10px;
        max-width: 90%;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 640px ) {
    .slider1_container {
        border-width: 5px;
    }
}
```

And also, `jssor.js` is missing in your code. Please replace

```
<script src="../js/jssor.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="../js/jssor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jssor.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Edit**

```
<div id="slider1_container" class="slider1_container" ...
```

**Move thumbnails**

Slides are always in `slides` container. If you make `slides` container smaller than `slider1_container`, then you have rest space to place your `thumbnail navigator`. You can use css to set position of your `thumbnailnavigator`, for example

```
<div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
```

Reference:

http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-arrange-layout-adjust-size.html
http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-ui-definition.html

Comment: Thanks very much for the help.

I couldn't (and still don't) understand what is meant by "use class name to define css for slider1_container".  Does this mean that I should rename the id to a class (#slider1_container becomes .slider1_container), or does it mean that I should add a class to the existing id?

I've tried both ways, and in either case, using your elements, the border is gone and the slider is no longer centred.

Comment: Using the exact instructions you've provided (changing #slider1_container to .slider1_container), you can see the result of this at http://divr.ca/new/index.html.  Pretty much a broken script altogether.  If you can suggest a remedy, I'm grateful.

Comment: You can see the result at http://divr.ca/new/index.html.  There is now a window for the thumbnail panel but no thumbnails.  Thanks sincerely.

Comment: Yes.  I'm quite sure that the page at divr.ca/new/index.html contains that code.

Comment: I don't think so. Please use the code in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I was uploading with an incorrect path, and the version you saw differed from the modified version.  Nonetheless, it appears that the slider cannot be styled with a border because when it is, it no longer is fully responsive.

Comment: I also tried to style the thumbnails so they will appear below the slider rather than overtop, but I was unable to move them.  Where do you suggest I style this?  Many thanks again.